# VirtualHost на своём сервере (сайте)

Tags: vps

На локальном хосте (например на windows) используя к примеру xampp мы можем создавать виртуальные адреса.

Можем ли мы создавать такие хосты на своём сервере на котором расположен наш домен и каким-то образом был доступен только для владельца домена?

Comment: Совершенно очевидно, что всё зависит от самого сервера. Можете купить дедик с виндой и поставить туда тот же самый xampp

Comment: Об этом я тоже подумал, даже взял дедик у амазона, поставил технологию ngrok. Однако как мне именно открыть этот виртуальный хост на своем сайт например через iframe?

Comment: Спасибо, решил вопрос)